# pycharm installed successfully but not launching in window 7

Tags: pycharm

Pycharm is successfully installed in my system but when I am trying to launch nothing is happening. I have installed Pycharm Community 2016.1.5. Can anyone help me here.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Oracle JRE 1.6+ or OpenJDK 1.7+.

To do that, check `$java -version` in your system terminal.

Comment: Yup I got it:) Thanks